# How can I create a "virtual joystick" based on GCController?

Tags: swift, joystick, gamecontroller

I'm building a framework to simplify the reuse of the GameController framework in game projects. When I had to think about unit tests, I realized that I can't emulate the joystick events, any ideas to help me?

Answer (score 0):

After some researches, I figured out how to solve the problem using the base classes of GameController framework. Take a look in unit tests sections of the project https://github.com/anderson-gusmao/ControlGameKit